# LINQ, convert Dictionary<int, bool> to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a

```
Dictionary<int, bool> articlesInfo = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
```

I need a the int and bool to be converted to string, into a

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

How is it possible via something like

```
Dictionary<string, string> newDictionary = 
    articlesInfo.Select(x => x.ToString(), y => y.ToString());
```

Comment: Why convert it, how are you using this dictionary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Dictionary<String,Int> to Dictionary<String,SomeEnum> using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716170/convert-dictionarystring-int-to-dictionarystring-someenum-using-linq) *specifically this answer* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/716195/1797425)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easiest to use Linq's [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__):

```
var newDictionary = 
    articlesInfo.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString(), x => x.Value.ToString());
```